# Kalman Filter on PID

Tags: signal-processing, kalman-filter, pid-controller

I'm not sure if this goes here, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the Kalman filter. What I want to do is condition a sensor with a PID compensator to find the optimal gains for the PID filter. This is a sort of pole balancing problem with video. I was wondering if someone could give a good explanation of the basics of the Kalman filter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most human readable intro with examples I have found so far is the [SIGGRAPH Course Pack](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~tracker/media/pdf/SIGGRAPH2001_CoursePack_08.pdf).

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. It seems to me you are trying to tune your PID controller but you do not need Kalman filter for that.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm hoping to get it to figure out the PID units. The problem I've been having so far is that there seems to be sufficient noise that I havent been able to get it to stabilize. It handles it fine for a short while, during which it's really shaky.